# Python, Firebird, FDB+SQLalchemy : ('Error while connecting to database:\n- SQLCODE: -551\n- no permission for read-write access

Tags: python, macos, permissions, sqlalchemy, firebird

I am struggling with connecting to Firebird database through pythons FDB driver and SQLalchemy.
My .fdb file is placed in my root folder /Users/me/db.fbd
I have firebird 2.5 classic server installed.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import fdb
import pandas as pd

database='//sysdba:masterkey@localhost:3050/Users/me/bd.fdb?charset=utf8'
database_driver='firebird+fdb'
encoding='UTF8'
conncection = ':'.join([database_driver, database])

engine = create_engine(conncection, encoding=encoding)

query = "Some query"
df = pandas.read_sql(sql=query_pay, con=engine)
```

This code constantly gives me and an error:

DatabaseError: (fdb.fbcore.DatabaseError) ('Error while connecting to database:\n- SQLCODE: -551\n- no permission for read-write access to database //Users/me/db.fdb', -551, 335544352) (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/4xp6)

At first I thought it was simple permissions issue, so I gave rights to read/write to all users (including firebird user) through graphical interface of OSX.
When this didn't work I even performed chmod 777 on db.fdb and it still doesn't work.
I should add that when I connect to this db using firebird terminal tool everything works just fine.

Do you have any ideas why I keep getting this error ? And how to fix it ?

Comment: strange file path in error text: `database //Users/me/db.fdb'` - why it starts with two slashes? are u sure connection string is properly formed?

Comment: If you are using firebird server, and the database is in your user folder, then the server does not have sufficient access rights to the database file. You should put the database file in a location where the server has access.

Comment: @Arioch'The This connection string worked for me pretty well before :(

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Even if I run chmod 777 on those ?

Comment: The error means that Firebird can open the database file, but it is unable to write to the file. So apparently, no.